# Network error on posting a request using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express, axios

When trying to post a http request using axios, I am getting following error:

```
Network Error
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:24 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:81:25 in handleError
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I tried replacing "proxy"="http://localhost:8080" with "http://myip:8080",  in package.json but the error persists.
I also tried using the fetch command f react native but it also gave the same error

package.json is:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.9",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "spectre.css": "^0.5.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

server.js is:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const app = express()
const PORT = 8080

// MIDDLEWARE
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
//routing
app.post('/', (req, res, next)=> {
    console.log('server post username: ');
    console.log(req.body.username)
    res.end()
})

// Starting Server 
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on PORT: ${PORT}`)
})
```

snippet for axios post is:

```
axios.post('/', {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                if (response.data) {
                    console.log('successful signup')
                    this.setState({
                        redirectTo: '/login'
                    })
                } else {
                        console.log('Sign-up error');

                    }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('Sign up server error: ')
                console.log(error);
            })
```

The output on executing the above code is:

```
Sign up server error: 

Network Error
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:24 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:81:25 in handleError
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved,I was using wrong IP(172.0.0.1) given by `hostname --ip-address`. Using the inet ip given by `ip addr show` works.

Answer (score 0):

first I suggest you too use different route namespaces instead of using `app.post('/')` try `app.post(`/api`), secondly you are not sending any data to client or any status code. try following:

```
app.post('/api/post', (req, res, next)=> {
    console.log('server post username: ');
    console.log(req.body.username)
    return res.status(200).send({redirectTo: '/login'});
 })
```

and axios

```
 axios.post('/api/post', {
     username: this.state.username,
     password: this.state.password
 })
 .then(response => {
       console.log('successful signup')
       this.setState({
            redirectTo: '/login'
       })

 }).catch(error => {
       console.log('Sign up server error: ')
       console.log(error);
 })
```

Also i would suggest you to use `cors` library for Cross Origin requests. download it from npm (or yarn or whatever)

and instead of

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, 
  DELETE');
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content- 
Type, Accept");
   next();
});
```

use this

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: I tried all the changes you suggested, but I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: then problem is in somewhere else. try to get error message somehow. instead logging error. log `error.message`

Comment: (in `axios` request)

Comment: what does it print

Comment: `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'error.response.data')]
* components/sign-up.js:37:36 in <unknown>
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals`

Comment: wow interesting. try opening issue on axios repository (github)

Comment: i don't think its an issue with axios becuase i am getting same error on using fetch as well

Comment: then i can not help you.

Comment: The middleware you suggested was not even accepting POST request from RESTful, so I changed it to `app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(
 bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
 })
)
app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: you mean cors? it is for cross origin requests but for requests you need bodyparser of course